# XML Parsing error on DOM load

Tags: php, xml, parsing, dom, domdocument

I have the xml file below (named as test.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<films>
<film>
<title rating="7.8">The Three Amigos</title>
<category>comedy</category>
<director>John Landis</director>
<country>United States</country>
</film>
<film>
<title rating="9.1">Brief Encounter</title>
<category>romance</category>
<director>David Lean</director>
<country>Great Britain</country>
</film>
</films>
```

Now, when running the below php code, I'm getting an error:

> "XML Parsing Error: junk after document element **Warning**:  DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load0]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "" in line 5".

I have no idea why the error is thrown. Please help.

```
<?php
$file = 'test.xml';
$doc = new DOMDocument();

$doc->load($file);


header("Content-Type: text/xml");
print $doc->saveXML();
?>
```

Comment: Please add a binary hex dump of the XML file to your question.

Comment: what happens when you just echo file_get_contents($file);? (I know you don't want that as the end product, but it could be that the file can't be found)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe some hidden or crunched characters around line 5?

Your script is running fine on my PHP 5.3.

You can try strip your XML to the smallest possible like:

```
<films></films>
```

Then add your original file element by element.

Comment: What happens? Same message with other line? You can try to make it more simple and load the XML inline by string and bypass the file loading stuff http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php

Comment: i tried:  <?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML('<root><node/></root>');
echo $doc->saveXML();
?>                                                                   and it outputs:                                               loadXML('A'); echo $doc->saveXML(); ?>